# Snapshot directory has log files. Check if dataLogDir and dataDir configuration is correct. + Zookeeper startup

Tags: apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform

Whenever I'm starting my zookeeper server, I'm getting the below error.

```
[2020-05-12 08:11:43,510] ERROR Unexpected exception, exiting abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain)
org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog$SnapDirContentCheckException: Snapshot directory has log files. Check if dataLogDir and dataDir configuration is correct.
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.checkSnapDir(FileTxnSnapLog.java:140)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.<init>(FileTxnSnapLog.java:109)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.runFromConfig(QuorumPeerMain.java:141)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:114)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:81)
```

Here is what I have in my zookeeper.properties

```
dataDir=/var/appdata/zookeeper
dataLogDir=/var/applogs/zookeeper
```

Answer (score 2):

The default setting in zookeeper is that the snapshot and log files are stored in the same directory(the **dataDir** dir). Now that you have started your cluster the system would have created both the logs and snapshot files in the same directory.

Later on when you decide to have separate folders(maybe to increase efficiency) for data(snapshot) and logs(log) files you would simply added the two properties (dataDir,dataLogDir) and restart your cluster . But this will not work and the server fails during startup saying "*Snapshot directory has log files*". This is right because your setting clearly demands unique folders for the two(but both the files are present in the same folder already in your case. So u have to migrate now).

**Soln:**
cut all the log files from the dataDir and paste inside the corresponding version folder(eg **version-2**) of the dataLogDir. This would help you resume your zookeeper from the previous state(snapshot).